# python processing message and return as list

Tags: python, list, file

Right now I have a function call  read_messages that takes one parameter
(file open for reading) and returns it as list of string. The parameter represents an open message file, which contains one message per line. I have to make the function read and return the contents of the file as a list of messages.
Also i have to strip the newline from each line. Right now i only opened my file but not sure how to read the lines of the message

```
read_messages(file_name):
    for line in open(file_name):
```

If i wanted to change my code so it works for a file containing a list of integer from 1-26 instead of strings how would i change my code so that its not the exact same as reading a string. And also would it be the exact same code?
So instead of opening a list of message from a text file I would read a list of integers from a text file like [1 2 3 4 5] and the print it out [1,2,3,4,5] 
Just to see if theres any difference

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Hi! It's not clear what your question is; can you provide more information? For future reference, this SO article provides a helpful guideline for *posting a question*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, here is a helpful guideline on *what not to ask*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want that or not, but that code splits newline and forms a  list where each line of the file is a list element.

```
def read_messages(file_name,'r'):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return f.read().splitlines() # Will return a list
```

If your input file is like below:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 3 5 4 6]
```

And the output you want is a python list for each line, you can try `literal_eval` to make a string into valid python expression.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("example.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        modifiedString=",".join(line.split(" "))
        output_list=literal_eval(modifiedString)
        print output_list
```

Comment: shouldn't there be no : after read_messages(file_name) since i tried it and it gave me a syntax error but when i delete it the error is gone

Comment: @naruto321, for defining a function, you need `def`. You clearly missed that. This is a run code and no chance of syntax error at least.

Comment: Also if i want it to read a deck of card file and make it return as a list of integers from 1-26 how would I change the code